# Print all of the possible combinations with numbers

Tags: c++, python, c, math, factorial

So, my idea is quite simple: print all of the possible combinations given X numbers...

For example, I have two numbers, 1 and 0, so the program print:

```
(0,0)
(0,1)
(1,0)
(1,1)
```

... Any idea to do this with C, C++ or Python? (If you know how to do this with other lenguage, please help me anyway).

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see what your sample output has to do with `x!`...

Comment: Um, how are those four tuples related to `x!`?

Comment: You have x! and the program prints (0,0), (0,1)...? What is x here???

Comment: Why would `x!` produce four combinations (and 4 is not the factorial of any integer)?  You have not told us what a factorial has to do with two-element combinations of a two-element alphabet.

Comment: Recurse. Base case: a list with 1 number. case n: print each of the n numbers followed by the list of n-1 numbers.

Comment: So what should 0,1,2 produce? (0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,0,2) and so forth or (0,0), (0,1), (0,2)...???? Problem still ambiguous.

Comment: If it is a permutation, the answer for 2! would be (0,1), (1,0) 2 results=2!, for 3! = (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,0,2) (1,2,0) (2,0,1) (2,1,0) = 6 results, them what you want exactly.

Comment: @ChristopherMahan I'm guessing AI as we're supposed to guess the problem as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are at least a thousand hits for 'print all combinations' on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Use the below example and extend as per your need

```
>>> [x for x in itertools.product("01",repeat=2)]
[('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '1')]
>>>
```

Comment: Using the `repeat` argument is probably cleaner (scales up better, anyway.)

Comment: To get the result using numbers, `(0,1)` should be used as the first argument.